# Convert Swf logo and Brun to dvd player

Tags: flash

Hi I have made the swing login in flash and I want to export to avi format for dvd player, If I export to swf I can see my logo swing non-stop but when I export to avi and open in the Media Player the logo is swing 1-2 second and stop, How can I make the non-stop play my logo in the avi format and play in the DVD Player, I want to show on the TV for my customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logo swings only 2 seconds because that the total time of the animation. Then FLash just makes it loop.

when you convert it to avi, you should have some option to say "activate loop" or something like that depending on the program you are using.

for example, in photoshop there is "loop animation" and something similar in sonyvegas video editor.